# Why does the order of static members in java matter?

Tags: java, static, initialization

Why does the order of static members in java matter?

E.g.

```
public class A {
  static int i= 1;
  static int c = i;
  int a = c; <<------ ok
}
```

vs.

```
public class B {
  int a = c; <<--- compile error
  static int c = 1;
  static int i = c;
}
```

Why is Java designed such that this ordering makes a difference?  (I have edited my question based on an answer of ykaganovich)

Edit: Thank you all for your help !
I have tested my examples with non-static variables. It has exactly the same behaviour, so static doesn't play any role here. This question is misleading (at least for me). I will try to summarize your answers.

Edit **2**:

I will try to sum the answers up. For more info please read the answers below :)

a) Direct forward references in Java as:

```
static int i = c;
static int c = 1;
```

are very confusing. So it's not allowed in Java. 
  The main reason is  initialisation order.

b) The indirect forward references are allowed in Java

```
public class Test {
int i = c();
int c() { return c; }
  int c = 1;
}
```

c) You must define exactly the order of execution of variable declaration (or initialisation),
 it's only definition matter how this was this done in java. 
 In java this ordering is top-to-bottom.

d) The well-defined order provide a way to predictable results.

e) If you design your program well you will not have this issues.

Comment: I don't understand. What are you trying to find out?

Comment: If you have a more in-depth question, or a specific issue, feel free to edit your question and ask it.

Comment: Thank you! My question is WHY java is designed in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I can guess what you are asking here, your example code does not demonstrate it and I truly wonder how nobody noticed that. I have even inspected the entire revision history of your question and haven't found a single instance of a program which would actually produce a compiler error.

But, let me show you an example which *does* produce a compiler error which you may have in mind:

```
public class Test {
  int i = c;
  int c = 1;
}
```

What happens here is that you reference `c` in the initializer of `i`. Therefore you are trying to read a variable which hasn't been yet initialized. Note that this has nothing to do with *declaration* order (compile-time), only with initialization order (runtime). In Java, as in all other similar languages, the order of member declaration plays no role except in the capacity of implying the order of execution of member initializers.

Java has a check which prevents one initializer from reading a variable whose initializer has not yet run. Java has many other such checks because it was designed to try hard to protect the programmer from making silly mistakes. In the words of James Gosling, Java was meant to be a "blue collar" language. This should answer your "why" question.

Note that the specific compiler check we are discussing here is quite weak and works only for the most obvious cases. Consider this simple variation on the above program:

```
public class Test {
  int i = c();
  int c() { return c; }
  int c = 1;
}
```

No errors produced here. Java doesn't go as far as inspecting what you actually do in any method you call from the initializer.

Answer (score 5):

It matters if you're actually assigning values to the variables.

```
public class A {
  static int i = 0;
  static int c = i; //fine
}
```

vs

```
public class B {
  static int c = i; // compilation error
  static int i = 0;
}
```

** To updated question **

Ah, I see you understand that this is not allowed, but you want to know why.

Let's make it a little more interesting:

```
  public class A {
    static int c = boom();
    static int i = bam();

    private static int bam() {
      return c + 2;
    }

    private static int boom() {
      return i + 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("i: " + i);
      System.out.println("c: " + c);
    }
  }
```

output:

```
i: 3 
c: 1
```

if you move i and c around:

```
static int i = bam();
static int c = boom();
```

you get:

```
i: 2
c: 3
```

That's just to illustrate that order matters.

As to why forward references in variable assignments are not allowed, what would you expect this code to do?

```
static i = c;
static c = i++;
```

The answer is actually unambiguous in the sense that Java has to process it in the specific order as it is defined. So, this should be equivalent to:

```
static i = 0;
static c = 0;
static {
  i = c;
  c = i++;
}
```

But the first form is very confusing and therefore error-prone. My guess is that's why it was disallowed.

Comment: Thank you! But it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Good point ! I am not sure whether it is allowed with non-static variables also.

Answer (score 2):

The order of static members in a Java class is irrelevant. The code is compiled the exact same way. Also, your example is essentially meaningless because you're merely changing variable names for two identical classes.

EDIT: Since you changed your question, I will point you to ykaganovich's answer regarding the assigning of pre-declared reference variables to each other. Your original question is answer in my paragraph above.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase my question. The static initializer order is relevant.

Comment: @JohnN It's not a bad question, sorry if my response came off as curt. Just tryign to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

the order of static variables init and static blocks execution also provides a way to do predictable operations in which later on variables can depend on already init/processed variables.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean with predictable operations ?

Answer (score 1):

It's just the syntax of the *the java language*. Static blocks all get initialized at program run-time. Take this example:

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // some code
    }

    public void play() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

How does the JVM know to start this program? Does it create an instance of the class A to know how to run it? No - because the main method is declared static it is initialized at run-time, the main method detected and the program can run.

This is the same as in C# and C++.

This goes with any static variables or methods. They are all initialised at program run-time. What if you wanted to create a class and you needed to ensure it has certain variables available immediately - variables which were class-wide? Make them static. Similarly, you can create static blocks like so:

```
static {
    // whatever code is needed for initialization goes here
}
```

This allows more complicated code beyond simple variables to be run at startup. It also allows for better memory allocation and usage. See [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) for more information.

**Edit: (based on updated question)**

I'm not sure how to answer your question.

Static variables/blocks are all initialized at run-time. Despite this, the JVM still has to process each thing individually, meaning it needs some sort of order. If you put the static block containing `int a = c` AFTER the two lines of static declarations, that's fine.

If you put the static declaration before, the JVM has no idea what you are referring to and complains.

As to why that happens? That's just the syntax of the language. There isn't a better or more detailed reason than that. You could argue it should load everything into memory and then check everything else existed before doing anything, but that would be resource-heavy and a waste of memory.

I don't think I can give you a better or more detailed reason than that!

Comment: I am not sure it is only coincidence as in your example with Word and String. The designer of JAVA/C#  had reasons to do so.

Comment: @JohnN: I deleted that bit to be more concise. It allows better usage of memory amongst other things. Check out the link on my edit. THAT'S the point of static blocks of code.

Additionally, static variables are class-wide, not object specific. No matter how many objects you create, you only want one class variable. Understand?

Comment: I understand what are static block or variable. But the question is why the order of static declarations matters.

Comment: For the same reason instance variable order matters. If you execute the code you have in your question, it's fine and there's no difference. If you try and do something like increment a variable before the line assigning the variable, a complain is thrown. That's just the logic of the system. No matter if it loads everything at run time, it still processes everything one by one, so must get the information in some sort of order.

Comment: I cann't upvote, because I have upvoted your answer already. Did you read the answer of ykaganovich or Ashish ?

Comment: @JohnN: Amended my answer and I really can't go into any more detail than that. It's simply the syntax of the language. The JVM MUST know what it is dealing with.

Comment: The JVM doesn't have syntax. The *Java language* has syntax. The rest of your answer is basically meaningless or irrelevant.

Comment: @EJP: Fine, the Java language then. I fail to see how your answer improves on this in any shape or form, particularly as I stated the exact same thing that you did.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is Java designed such that this ordering makes a difference?

*Your program* is designed such that this ordering makes a difference. You are declaring variables whose values are interdependent, so some ordering has to be defined, and top to bottom is what is defined in Java, and indeed most languages. Your program as written doesn't make sense within top-to-bottom ordering. So fix it so that it does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course my program is the reason for this Java behavior. But the question is: why Java behave like that for my program.

Answer (score 1):

I try try to sum the answers up. For more info please read the answeres below :)

a) forward references in java as:

```
static int i = c;
static int c = i++;
```

are very confusing. So It's not allowed in java.

b) You must define exactly the order of execution of variable declaration,
 it's only definition matter how this was this done in java. 
 In java this ordering is top-to-bottom.

c) the well-defined order provide a way to predictable results.

d) if you design your program well you will not have this issues.

Comment: Forward references *are allowed in Java*.

Comment: Are you sure ? I've got 'forward references ' are not allowed error with Java 1.7 compiler.

Comment: Here Java is only stopping you from reading a variable whose initializer has not yet run. The concept of forward reference is more general than that: for example, you certainly can call a method defined below the place where you call it.

Comment: To make this perfectly relevant to your answer, declare `static int c() { return c; }` and replace the direct read with method call: `static i = c();`.